# Meaning of «сесть кому-н на шею»

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

> Но она тут же **села** **ему на шею** - как и всем своим бывшим парням.

This is part of an IM I received from my girlfriend, in which she was talking jokingly about her female friend bordering on control freak vis-à-vis her henpecked boyfriend seemingly at her beck and call.

In Japanese, there is an expression 尻に敷かれる, literally "a man is beneath the hips of his wife/girlfriend", albeit without specifying which part of his body she sits on. I wonder if this Russian expression is more or less the *neck version* of it?

Is the phrase "тут же / immediately" part of this idiom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must add that "сидеть на шее" isn't just to be a burden on somebody, it's taking advantage of someone, having someone to look after you when you're fully capable of looking after yourself.

Comment: Разве это не "под каблуком"?

Comment: "Под каблуком" совсем наоборот. Быть под каблуком означает быть в насильственном подчинении, обычно о мужчине. По-английски это "whipped" - a man made to be submissive to a woman.

Answer (score 5):

The idiom is. сидеть у кого-либо на шее — be a burden to smb, **live at smb's expense**. «Тут же» isn't included, meaning "immediately"

Your version corresponds to another idiom «быть под каблуком», which is a different kind of dependence.

> Он всю жизнь сидит на шее у родителей, палец о палец не ударил.